# Ruby: abort OpenURI based on content length

Tags: ruby, open-uri

Ruby's [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/classes/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#M001635) provides a `content_length_proc` option which allows determining* content length before the actual transfer is started:

```
open(url, :content_length_proc => lambda { |content_length|
  puts "Content Length: #{content_length}"
}) { |data|
   # data.meta, data.read etc.
}
```

Is there a way for this proc to abort the actual, full retrieval?

* I'm aware this is not reliable - but it's sufficient for a simple heuristic in my case

Comment: FWIW, op noted that `content-length` is not reliable. A reliable approach is to use `:progress_proc` which will report the total bytes each time a new chunk is pulled off the net. So you can abort if you get too much data based on actual bytes downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the corresponding code from open-uri.rb:

```
if options[:content_length_proc] && Net::HTTPSuccess === resp
  if resp.key?('Content-Length')
    options[:content_length_proc].call(resp['Content-Length'].to_i)
  else
    options[:content_length_proc].call(nil)
  end
end
resp.read_body {|str|
  ...
}
```

So as you can see the return value of `content_length_proc` is ignored. But, what you could simply do to cancel the operation is raise some form of error in the callback - this will effectively abort further execution. If you raise a dedicated error class you could even rescue it and react to that specific situation:

```
begin
  open(url, :content_length_proc => lambda { |content_length|
    puts "Content Length: #{content_length}"
  }) { |data|
    # data.meta, data.read etc.
  }
rescue MyError
  # react to it
end
```